# Unpredictable results with two threads calling a function

Tags: c, multithreading, real-time

I hoping someone can help me solve some unpredictable behaviour in a C program I need to fix:

I have two Xenomai real-time tasks (threads) that wait until they receive an incoming message from one of two CAN buses. 
Each task calls a function  checkMessageNumber()  however I'm getting unpredictable results.

Please note that I am using a priority based, single-threaded system. One thread has priority over the other, however one thread could be part-way through executing when the other thread takes priority. 
It the future it is possible that the hardware could be upgraded to a multi-threading system, however this part of the program would still be confined to a single thread (one CPU core).

It is my understanding that each thread would invoke it's own instance of this function so I don't know what's happening.

```
int getMessageIndex(unsigned int msg_number)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i < global_number_message_boxes)
    { 
        if (global_message_box[i].id == msg_number}
            return i; // matched the msg number, so return the index number
        i++;
    }
    return -1; // no match found
}
```

Originally this function was highly unpredictable, and as messages streamed in and were processed by the two tasks (depending on which hardware bus the message came from), this function would sometimes return -1 even though the incoming 'msg_number' did match an 'id' in the 'global_message_box' struct.

I was able to make it work better by setting 'global_number_message_boxes' to an integer: 
eg.  `while(i < 50)` 
however the function still sometimes returns -1 even though there should be a match.

I am only reading global variables, so why are they getting corrupted?  what do I need to learn about this?

My idea is to simplify things so the incoming 'msg_number' simply just is the 'id' in the 'global_message_box'.  
Each thread will then write to the struct directly without having to check which 'id' to write too. 
How important is it to use a mutex?  due to system design, each thread will never write to the same part of the struct, so I am unsure if it's important?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, the interesting bits are where these variables are WRITTEN...

Comment: How messages are sent to threads? Is there an interrupt handler that modifies your global structures and sends a message to tasks?

Comment: static unsigned int global_number_message_boxes = 0; 
However I still get the strange behaviour, albeit less, when loop to a static integer.

Comment: The function that writes to the global_message_box struct prints out an error when the ID number is -1, because it should never happen.

Comment: @MaximSkurydin: the two tasks are essentially interrupt handlers, that execute when a CAN message is received from their respective hardware bus.

Comment: 'essentially interrupt handlers' - are they, in fact interrupt-handlers?  If so, you cannot use locks as suggested by other posters.  What happens if, just as a test, you stop re-enabling higher-priority interrupts?

Comment: 'priority based, single-threaded system' - what calls this function? What triggers the calling of this function?  Which stack is this function called on?

Comment: What happens when a match is found?  What data is changed in global_number_message_boxes and how?

Answer (score 3):

This likely comes down to lack of thread synchronisation around the global struct: you say this function is just reading. Sure, but what if another thread calls another function that writes `global_number_message_boxes` or `global_message_box`? In a system where you have globals and multiple threads accessing them the safes rule is: put a lock around every access. Maybe the platform you use even supports read/write locks, so multiple threads can read at the same time as long as none is writing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  global_number_message_boxes is only defined at the start of the program.  I'm just trying to understand why there can be unpredictable behaviour when reading variables.  I will add a lock to the writing part.

Comment: you should read some resources on how threads work, I cannot really explain it well. Multiple threads can read from a memory location at the same time without problem. However when that memory location is being written to, and at the same time a thread reads from it, you gate undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah I was also just reading the comments on the question; it's hard to tell without more actual code. However since the OP says the tasks are waiting, and since you cannot do a lot of stuff in interrupt handler, I suppose the task/threads wait for a signal and that signal is set in the actual interrupt handler so the tasks do not run in the interrupt context. At least that's how you mostly do things on RT systems.

Answer (score 1):

Lock and Semaphores will be your friends here. Writing data using two threads is going to cause any number of problems.

When the thread enters the function, you will have to BLOCK the other threads and UNBLOCK those threads at exit. This will ensure thread-safe operations and produce consistent results.